# Is incongruous RAM'ing (using two memory chips with difference in RAM size) ineffective?

Tags: memory, performance

I heard someone say that using 8GB RAM plus 16 GB ram (DDR3)in two slots is same or even worse performance-wise than using two identical 8GB ram chips, and that it only improves performance when you use DDR4 S0-DIMM RAM sticks.
Is this true?

If yes, why?
And if one does upgrade, should the 2nd ram stick always be of the same or a lower frequency?

Sub-question, but feel free to ignore this if you're overloaded: what is the role of frequency, as in: what should we take heed of?

Comment: You seem to be referring to *dual channel* operation, but not accurately.  If your system is severely memory starved (i.e. it would benefit from having more memory) then simply having more memory (albeit slower) could be better than the existing situation of limited but fast memory.  To a certain extent processor cache can alleviate use of slower memory.  BTW memory is installed using memory modules (i.e. the "MM" in DIMM), rather than *"memory chips"*.

Comment: @sawdust advice is golden.  To elaborate, "memory chips" are what are soldered onto the "memory modules" :)  Running dual channel ram is optimal but negligible compared to not having the ram avail. in the first place.